# Limit number of steps in boost::odeint integration

Tags: c++, boost, differential-equations, odeint

Say that I have the following `boost::odeint` code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

const double sigma = 10.0;
const double R = 28.0;
const double b = 8.0 / 3.0;

typedef boost::array< double , 3 > state_type;

void lorenz( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t ){
    dxdt[0] = sigma * ( x[1] - x[0] );
    dxdt[1] = R * x[0] - x[1] - x[0] * x[2];
    dxdt[2] = -b * x[2] + x[0] * x[1];
}

void write_lorenz( const state_type &x , const double t ){
    cout << t << '\t' << x[0] << '\t' << x[1] << '\t' << x[2] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    state_type x = { 10.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 }; // initial conditions
    cout<<"Steps: "<<integrate( lorenz , x , 0.0 , 25.0 , 0.1 , write_lorenz )<<endl;
}
```

How can I modify the code so that integrate will break after a certain number of steps? I'm running a large number of integrations and want to avoid spending too much time on integrating any particular system.

I've thought of using `integrate_n_steps()`, but this may mean that the integration proceeds past the end time I am interested in.

Comment: So you want to fix the real time spending, rather than the number of step? After the break, what are you expecting? Give up the integration or output somethign similar?

Comment: @hwlau, I'd like to give up the integration. Cutting of by a fixed number of steps or by time-of-execution would both work, though I wish the program to keep running after the break: only the integrator should stop.

Answer (score 5):

there is no integrate routine for this task at the moment. Nevertheless, you have several options:

**First,** use an observer in integrate() and throw an exception there if you exceed the number of maximal steps. Of course, this is not very elegant:

```
struct write_lorenz_and_check_steps
{
    size_t m_steps;
    write_lorenz_and_check_steps( void ) : m_steps( 0 ) { }
    void operator()( const state_type &x , const double t ) const {
       cout << t << '\t' << x[0] << '\t' << x[1] << '\t' << x[2] << endl;
       ++m_steps;
       if( m_steps > max_steps ) throw runtime_error( "Too much steps" );
    }
};

// ...

size_t steps = 0;
try {
    steps = integrate( lorenz , x , 0.0 , 25.0 , 0.1 , write_lorenz );
} catch( ... ) { steps = max_steps; }
cout << steps << endl;
```

**Second**, you can write the stepping loop yourself:

```
// Attention: the code has not been check to compile
double tmax = 25.0;
size_t imax = 1000;
size_t i = 0;
auto stepper = make_dense_output( 1.0e-6 , 1.0e-6 , runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type >() );
stepper.initialize( x , t , dt );
while ( ( stepper.current_time() < tmax ) && ( i < imax ) )
{
    observer( stepper.current_state() , stepper.current_time() );
    stepper.do_step( lorenz() );
    ++i;
}
x = stepper.current_state();
```

In this example you also work directly with `stepper.current_state()` and `stepper.current_time()` instead of calling the observer. Furthermore, if you compiler does not support auto, i.e. you have a C++03 compiler just use

```
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< state_type > stepper_type;
result_of::make_dense_output< stepper_type >::type stepper =
    make_dense_output( 1.0e-6 , 1.0e-6 , stepper_type() );
```

We are also developing a special integrate routine exactly for this task. But it will still take some weeks until it is finished. Furthermore, we develop ode iterators which could also be used and which will be ready very soon (I hope at the next of next week).

Comment: The first method is pretty standard. You mention developing, so are you considering to add real computational time limited/ walled clock time limited version?

Comment: @headmyshoulder, is there a line like this `stepper.do_step( lorenz() );` to call an observer function? I'm aware I could just write one in, but that seems to break (conceptually) the encapsulation of the stepper class.

Comment: And, in the second code block, do you happen to know what the type of the `stepper` variable may be? `auto` doesn't work well in class definitions.

Comment: @hwlau We are developing a generic conditional integrate function with custom break conditions. In principle you can add the wall clock time limits to the break condition, if this makes sense for you.

Comment: @Richard I have added some notes about the observer and the auto keyword to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @headmyshoulder! It'd be great if you could put up links to the appropriate documentations once those integrators become available. In the meantime, perhaps you have insights into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484134/set-current-state-in-odeint) question?